# Reduce job in Spark by reduceByKey() or other functions?

Tags: python, mapreduce, apache-spark, reduce, pyspark

Given the following list:

```
[(0, [135, 2]), (0, [2409, 1]), (0, [12846, 2]), (1, [13840, 2]), ...]
```

I need to output a list of first elements of the list-value (i.e., `135, 2409, 12846` for key `0` and `13840` for key `1`) for each key if the second element of the list-value (i.e., `2, 1, 2` for `0` and `2` for `1`) is greater than or equal to a certain value (let's say 2). For instance, in this particular case the output should be:

```
[(0, [135, 12846]), (1, [13840]), ...]
```

The tuple `(0, [2409, 1])` is discarded because `1 < 2`.

I've achieved that by applying a `groupByKey()`, a `mapValues(list)` and a final `map` function, but clearly `groupByKey()` is less efficient than reduce functions.

Is this possible achieving that task by just using a `reduceByKey()` or `combineByKey()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes :) You can achieve the same with a `reduceByKey` as with a `groupByKey`. In fact, `reduceByKey` should always be favoured as it performs a map side reduce before shuffling data.

A solution using `reduceByKey` (in Scala, but I'm sure you get the point, and can easily convert it to Python if you prefer):

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((0, List(135, 2)), (0, List(2409, 1)), (0, List(12846, 2)), (1, List(13840, 2))))
rdd.mapValues(v => if(v(1) >= 2) List(v(0)) else List.empty)
   .reduceByKey(_++_)
```

Comment: Thanks Glennie. Just a question to better understand how to translate Scala code in Python code: what does ``++`` means in scala? Is it a simple sum?

Comment: `++` is a list concatenation. In Python just use `+`.

Comment: Glennie, _always_ is far to strong word here. Something like _is preferred when function can reduce amount of data_ would be a better choice.

Comment: @zero323 Yes, you're right. I guess I just want to encourage people to think about `reduceByKey` before they go for a `groupByKey`. I find that far too many `groupByKey` are usually used.

Comment: Perfect, thank you again! I've translated the scala code into python code: ``rdd.mapValues(lambda x: [x[0]] if x[1] >= 3 else []).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)``